# Powershell to get Hotfix information

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003, hotfix

I'm looking to get Windows Hotfix information from 2003 servers. For this im using the following PowerShell script as Get-Hotfix does not return all the installed dates. What I would like to do is get only updates applied after a certain date. How could this be done?

```
    $computername = "Compter01"
    $HotFix = Get-WmiObject win32_ntlogevent -filter "(logfile='system') AND (sourcename='ntservicepack')" -cn $computername |
    select @{name="ServerName"; e={$_.__Server}},Message,@{label="Date Installed"; expression={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.TimeWritten)}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = [datetime]'1/1/2013'
$computername = "Compter01"
$HotFix = Get-WmiObject win32_ntlogevent -filter "(logfile='system') AND (sourcename='ntservicepack')" -cn $computername | 
    Where {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeWritten) -gt $date} | 
    Select @{name="ServerName"; e={$_.__Server}},Message,@{label="Date Installed"; expression={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.TimeWritten)}}
```

There may be a way to filter out dates using the WMI filter query but that's not my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for this I had to use this  Get-Date '1/1/2013' for it to work.